# Alternate for Teamviewer

Tags: 12.04, windows, teamviewer

I have been using Teamviewer to connect my Windows machine from ubuntu for the past three months. Now I'm facing an inconvenience to use Teamviewer.

I'm using team viewer to connect remote desktop of windows. I don't have any dedicated IP and my modem doesn't support any free DDNS services so I'm not able to use inbuilt remote desktop connection feature in windows.

Does anybody can suggest me a good alternate program to use in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: I could ... but instead I recommend a new operating system : Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS ... Ubuntu 12.04 will get unsupported in less than two months, and by the way, TeamViewer is one of the best solutions of its kind ... you'll hardly find something better ! :)

Comment: @user535733 Question edited :)

Answer (score 1):

Team-viewer is available for Ubuntu.

[32-bit version.](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux.deb)

[64-bit version](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb)

There are some alternatives too.

[RDP](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/06/connect-to-ubuntu-11-04-from-windows-via-remote-desktop/)

[VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)

You can also try [ScreenConnect](http://www.screenconnect.com/)

Comment: As i mentioned in my question i'm using TV now. And for rdp i don't have any dedicated ip and my modem is not supporting free DDNS services. VNC could be an option, let me try that one.

Comment: You can also try ScreenConnect. I've edited my answer. Take a look

Comment: @Rooney Please let us know is it worked or not. If it didn't work out so I'll try some other way, or just tell if it is done, so that other viewers of this question be sure about the answer.

Comment: I fixed the issue by configuring a DDNS client software in the remote machine. Thanks for the help.